# PHP regular expression to replace UTF-8 characters except alphanumerics, dot and hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I am doing a preg replace on a string which should contain only alphanumeric (utf-8), dots, spaces and hyphens only. Can you please suggest me a regular expression to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^-\pL.\s]/u', '', $entity);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I am using below words "Как здесь добавить"

Comment: @Nagarjun what do you mean it doesn't work?  What characters aren't being removed that you expect to be removed?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your edited regex. the updated one works correctly. Thanks.

Comment: note that `\s` matches `[\t\r\n\f\ ]` if you *only* need to match the regular space you can use `\x20` instead